# Etimologia de "sirigaita"

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica

Qual a origem da palavra *sirigaita*?

Obs.: Pesquisando com o Google já encontrei uma explicação provável "talvez do asturiano xirigata 'vozerio, algazarra'". A tentativa aqui é comprovar/refutar a explicação apresentada.

Comment: O dicionário Houaiss também diz que a origem "é talvez o asturiano *xirigata*".

Comment: Sirigaita também é uma ave (https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/sirigaita) que é conhecida por ser trepadeira (subir em árvores e arbustos).  Sendo a palavra *trepar* também sinônimo chulo do ato sexual (pelo menos no Brasil), esse pode ser o motivo da palavra ser empregada com esse cunho pejorativo.

Comment: @Peixoto, a conotação sexual de sirigaita parece ser relativamente recente. O Bluteau em 1720 diz só que é menina irrequieta (além do pássaro).

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com o *Michaelis Dicionário Brasileiro da Língua Portuguesa* (2015), "sirigaita" pode ser derivada do étimo "xirigata", palavra da língua asturiana, falada na região de Astúrias, Espanha. Assim como o português e castelhano, o asturiano é uma língua românica.

Ainda segundo o dicionário supracitado, "sirigaita" denota uma mulher desinibida e chamativa, que busca atenção. Há também a variante gráfica "serigaita".

Consultando o *Dicionário Unesp do português contemporâneo* (2004, p. 1292), "sirigaita" é de **origem duvidosa** (Or duv) e também denota "uma mulher buliçosa e leviana". A palavra pode ser tanto um adjetivo como substantivo (p. ex., "Ela considera a vizinha uma sirigaita").

O texto chamado *Amostra de verbetes inéditos da 18ª edição de "onde vêm as palavras"*, escrito pelo Prof. Dr. Deonísio da Silva (USP), pode ajudar em sua busca, confira o item 40 do documento.

Estabeceler a etimologia de uma palavra, em qualquer língua natural, é uma tarefa árdua e requer poderosos instrumentos que são geralmente indisponíveis. Podemos concluir que "sirigaita" **pode vir** do asturiano, cuja acepção nessa língua relaciona-se com a palavra no português: uma mulher chamativa (sirigaita) pode ser barulhenta (xirigata: **algazarra**, **vozerio**). Mesmo assim, não há consenso entre os lexicógrafos sobre sua origem.

**Referências**

DA SILVA, Deonísio. AMOSTRA DE VERBETES INÉDITOS DA 18ª EDIÇÃO DE “DE ONDE VÊM AS PALAVRAS”. **PRINCIPIA**, [S.l.], n. 29, p. 1-8, jan. 2015. ISSN 2358-7326. Disponível em: https://www.e-publicacoes.uerj.br/ojs/index.php/principia/article/view/13981/10675. Acesso em: 02 jan. 2019. DOI: https://doi.org/10.12957/principia.2014.13981

SIRIGAITA. In: BORBA, Francisco da Silva (Org.). **Dicionário Unesp do português contemporâneo**. São Paulo: UNESP, 2004, p. 1292.

SIRIGAITA. In: MICHAELIS Dicionário Brasileiro da Língua Portuguesa. 2015. Disponível em: https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/sirigaita/. Acesso em: 02 jan. 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Essa é a hipótese mais aceite, mas apenas como hipótese. Foram sugeridas outras. Antenor Nascente ([*Dicionário Etimológico da Língua Portuguesa*, 1955](https://archive.org/stream/AntenorNascentesDicionaroEtimologicoDaLinguaPortuguesaTomoI/DicionarioEtimolgicoDaLinguaPortuguesa#page/n511/mode/2up)) sugere relação com o espanhol *zirigaña*, ‘adulador’. Eunice Marta no [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-origem-da-palavra-sirigaita/30992) interroga-se se haverá “relação com o apelido italiano (antigo ) *Sirigatti*”

O dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002) apresenta a hipótese asturiana. Citando (desenvolvo algumas abreviações):

> **serigaita** *s.f*. (1720 cf. Bluteau) **1** mulher vivaz, ladina, buliçosa **1.1** mulher que usa requebros para seduzir, atrair **2** menina excessivamente desembaraçada, com resposta, para tudo ʘ ETIM talvez o asturiano xirigata ‘vozerio, algazarra’ e, este, do francês antigo *eschirgaite*, variante de *eschargaite* ‘patrulha que monta a guarda, emboscada’, donde o espanhol *zaragata* ‘bulha, confusão’, origem do português *zaragata* ‘idem’, outra variante é o francês antigo *eschargarde* ‘idem’, donde o espanhol *zalagarda* ‘emboscada para apanhar descuidado o inimigo’, todas procedem do frâncico **skarawahta*, de *skara* ‘destacamento’ + *wahta* ‘guarda’; ver zaraga e saragata

Agora, eu fiquei mais convencido da ligação ente *xirigata* e *sirigaita* quando vi o significado antigo de *sirigaita* e os outros significados de *xirigata* além de ‘vozerio, algazarra’.

***Xirigata*** pode significar, de acordo com este [Diccionario General de la Lengua Asturiana](https://mas.lne.es/diccionario/palabra/52012), e traduzindo (espero que bem) para português, ‘coisa miúda, de pouca importância’; *xirigatu* ou *xirigote* significa ‘excessivamente delgado’ ou ‘que faz “xirigotiaes”’, que segundo este [*El Hable de Cabrane* (1944)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=RjjW4_gc95IC&pg=PA366&lpg=PA366&dq=xirigotiaes&source=bl&ots=uMZhgmw5mK&sig=x_KfBfJ5gUCoxvTrK4yeRUkf6wo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKq7_IvNnfAhUu-YUKHb-_CcoQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=xirigotiaes&f=false) significa ‘macaquices, bobagens para fazer rir’.

E o significado de ***sirigaita*** apresentado nos dicionários atualmente parece ser relativamente recente. Em 1720, Raphael Bluteau no [*Vocabulário Português e Latino*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=3OYPDGOWagUC&pg=PA662&lpg=PA662&dq=%22Sirigaita.%20Coufa%20muyto%20inquieta%22&source=bl&ots=H0tmLbDcWM&sig=XKmgNeT1C0wdTi8Nne5wHUCeWG8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjI77_9lNrfAhVR5eAKHVy-D0EQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Sirigaita.%20Coufa%20muyto%20inquieta%22&f=false) define (grafia original):

> Sirigâita. He um passarinho, que trepa pelas arvores. He de cor de hũa carriça, & do tamanho de hum pintassilgo, com bico mais comprido do q̃ qualquer do seu tamanho.
>   Sirigaita. Cousa muyto inquieta, que anda de hũa parte para outra, diz-se particularmente das meninas.

Esta ênfase nas meninas mantém-se durante mais de um século. Em 1773 Anthony Vieira [(*A Dictionary of the Portuguese and English Languages*)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=MTZAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PT4&dq=%E2%80%9Ca%20restless%20child,%20or%20girl%20that%20is%20always%20in%20motion%E2%80%9D&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkq82EltrfAhVJjZAKHePdA1sQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9Ca%20restless%20child%2C%20or%20girl%20that%20is%20always%20in%20motion%E2%80%9D&f=false), diz que é “a restless child, or girl that is always in motion”. Em 1831 a [3ª edição do dicionario de Moraes Silva](https://books.google.pt/books?id=lwxaAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA730&dq=%22menina%20inquieta,%20andeja%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM5a_oltrfAhXLEJAKHSOsCXQQ6AEIOTAC#v=onepage&q=%22menina%20inquieta%2C%20andeja%22&f=false), além do passarinho, diz “pessoa, e principalmente menina inquieta, andeja”; a 4ª edição não encontrei; a [5ª, de 1858,](https://books.google.pt/books?id=lTBxS8oISF4C&pg=PA822&dq=%22menina%20inquieta,%20andeja%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM5a_oltrfAhXLEJAKHSOsCXQQ6AEIQTAD#v=onepage&q=%22menina%20inquieta%2C%20andeja%22&f=false) é que já acrescenta “requebrada, com maneiras attractivas, seductoras”. E por fim, no [dicionário de Cândido Figueiredo de 1899](https://archive.org/details/novodiccionriod01figugoog/page/n544)  é que já vem a definição atual, sem referência a crianças. Curiosamente, o significado que eu conhecia era o antigo, ‘menina irrequieta’. Eu cresci numa zona rural, e estas zonas conservam por vezes usos linguísticos antigos.

Ora então temos *xirigata* que significa ‘coisa miúda, de pouca importância’ e ‘pessoa que faz macaquices’; e *sirigaita* que há trezentos anos significava principalmente ‘menina irrequieta’. Sempre é uma relação mais próxima do que entre ‘algazarra’ e ‘mulher ladina’. Portanto, na minha opinião, que vale o que vale, dadas as semelhanças na forma e significado, parece-me que haverá de facto ligação entre o português e o asturiano. Agora, se *sirigaita* vem de *xirigata*, ou se partilham uma origem comum é que já são outros quinhentos.

Comment: O único significado que conheço também é o **2** — é simplesmente uma miúda mais safadazita.

Comment: @Artefacto, na minha aldeia, era uma criança, nem sequer adolescente; mas os outros significados lá vêm no dicionários já desde o sXIX. Eu encontrei em textos do sXIX coisas como, *namora para lá um sirigaita*; pode ter evoluído por aí: uma aplicação algo jocosa/depreciativa a mulheres jovens.